# get value radiobutton in controller and check (angular)

Tags: angularjs, controller, radio-button

I'm creating a little quiz, I get my questions and answers from a json file. After you answered a question you need to click the 'next question' button. By doing this, I need to check if the answer is correct (and also remember because I want to show the totalscore at the end).

How can I do this? I really have no idea, I just started using angular...

## HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:ids">
{{question.question}}
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.answers"><input type="radio" name="rAnswer" value="{{answer.answer}}">{{answer.answer}}
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="next()" value="{{buttonText}}">
```

## Controller

```
lycheeControllers.controller('quizCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('json/questions.json').success(function (data) {
    //all questions
    $scope.questions = data;

    //filter for getting answers / question
    $scope.ids = function (question) {
        return question.id == number;
    }

    $scope.buttonText = "Next question";

    $scope.next = function () {
        if (!(number == (data.length))) {
            if(number+1==(data.length)){
                $scope.buttonText = "Get results";
            }
            number++;
        }
    }
});
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add `ng-model="answer.selected"` to the ng-repeated `input`. Now you can loop through and look where answer.selected is true and that's your answer.

Another approach, if you don't want to mess with your model, would be to do something like `$scope.response = [];` in your controller, then set `ng-model="response[$index]"` in your template. Then $scope.response will hold all the values and you can loop through to see where your data is.

as a side note: You might also find it easier to set $scope.question rather than your filtering technique.